# miner.start() is not a function?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, web3js-v1.x

"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"

"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.55"

```
import {Miner} from 'web3-eth-miner';
```

then

```
  const options = {
        defaultAccount: "0x78dB3e2129D58685444989dD9682DDDC70dd3C82",
        defaultBlock: 'latest',
        defaultGas: 1,
        defaultGasPrice: 0,
        transactionBlockTimeout: 50,
        transactionConfirmationBlocks: 24,
        transactionPollingTimeout: 480,
      }
      const miner = new Miner("http://127.0.0.1:9545", null,options);
      console.log(miner); miner.start(2);
```

miner.start() says that it is not a function()...
ref : https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-miner.html

Comment: You're doing `console.log(miner)`. Sure you can elaborate on the output of that line!

Comment: try miner.startMining("0x2")

Comment: @MajdTL miner.startMining("0x2") gives error TypeError: miner.startMining is not a function

Comment: @goodvibration console.log(miner) returns Proxy {providerResolver: ProviderResolver, givenProvider: Proxy, _currentProvider: HttpProvider, _defaultAccount: "0x78dB3e2129D58685444989dD9682DDDC70dd3C82", _defaultBlock: "latest", …}
[[Handler]]
:
Object
[[Target]]
:
Miner
[[IsRevoked]]
:
false

Comment: And what does `npm ls web3` tells you when you run it from the same place you run your script?

Comment: @goodvibration `npm ls web3` returns `client@0.1.0 /home/tops/Desktop/arjun/blockchain/react5/react6/client` 
`-- web3@1.0.0-beta.37 `

Comment: Note that the official documentation (which you have linked) states: "The RPC method used is `miner_start`". If your provider (i.e., the remote process) does not support this function, then the RPC (remote procdure call) will fail. That said, what is your provider (i.e., what process is listening on your port 9545)?

Comment: @goodvibration I'm using `truffle react-box` which gives 10 demo account with 100ether each when we do `truffle develope`

Comment: That's not the web3-provider side, that's the web3-client side. In the web3 protocol (as in any comm protocol) there are two sides. The client side can be, for example, a node.js script which you run on your local machine. Truffle wraps this script and allow you to "write it nicely". This script runs in a process which ultimately communicates with another process, where the web3-provider is running. The provider would typically be an Ethereum Node application. For example - Geth, Parity, Ganache, etc. Which one of those are you running on port 9545?

Comment: @goodvibration I've also tried starting rpc server using `geth --rpc` and then it gave me `"http://127.0.0.1:8545"` endpoint to so i listned on that ..but it still says that miner.start() and miner.startMining() function not found.

Comment: @goodvibration it throws an error TypeError: miner.startMining is not a function

Comment: @Arjun add the web3 version to the question, and see my answer down

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with web3@1.0.0-beta.37, cause web3-eth-miner has been added lately, 
update web3 to 1.0.0-beta.55

old version

[image]

new version

[image]

Comment: I've tried to upgrading the `"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.55",` still same error that  `TypeError: miner.startMining is not a function`

Comment: check the version of web3 js in your package.json, and delete nodes modules and package.lock and then try npm install and miner.start(2) ?

Comment: that didn't worked. web3-eth-miner is an sub module which need to gets installed additionally.

Comment: modules and methods are changed and new startMining method doesn't work as well. ref :https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/docs/web3-eth-miner.rst